# Different display value from real value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, choice-field, concatenate

Is it possible to have a different display value from the actual value of the field ?
I would like to have a choice field with category codes and the actual category but only the code must show up once selected. e.g.  Field Choice = 004 - Blue <--- once selected only 004 shows up in results.

I am no developer but i am busy with concatenate and not getting it right. Is this possible outside of too much programming ?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online or On-Premise?

Comment: The test server is On-prem, once the solution works the way we want we will probably go online with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible directly to set the choice column to have two set of values(display value and actual value). However we have some out of box workarounds you can try.

1. We can set two columns, one choice column and one calculated column.
   This will work when you do not have many choices for users to
   select, because it is not very convenient to write a complicated
   nested IF condition for the calculated column.

   It works like this, the choice column holds all the choices with the
   display value for users to choice. And in the list view, hide it and
   only display the calculated column. Then we write the IF formula for
   calculated column to set value based on the choice column.
2. Mostly like the first one, however we do not use calculated column if you have access to Power Automate. Just create another choice column holding the actual value.  Then we can create a flow to handle the work. When the item is created or modified, get the value from the choice column holding the display value and then update the actual value column with corresponding value. Like user choose Blue in the display column, then the flow update the actual column with 004.

Comment: Thank you i will definitely try these

Comment: Option 1 worked for me, used Left function to cut out the first field. Thank you so much